# selenium wait expected conditions not working

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click the google store once the google webpage loads. I do not want to use `time.sleep()` for a few seconds for the google page to load in. I want the browser to click "store" once the page loads. Below is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pause

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/applications/chromedriver')
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.xpath, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a[2]")))
element.click()
```

The html for xpath is correct too since it works with `driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a[2]").click()`

Comment: try XPATH of "//a[contains(@href, 'store.google.com')]" But you really don't need a wait there.  Selenium will already wait for the page to be ready after .get()

Comment: I checked your code. It turns out that your xpath is wrong, the correct version (for German version of Google) that worked for me was `"/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[2]"`

Comment: "//a[text()='Store']" would also work.